# difference between dataframe.pop and dataframe.drop pandas python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I was wondering what the difference between the 2 functions is. Does `dataframe.pop` just remove the column and return the removed column while `dataframe.drop` only removes the column

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `DataFrame.drop` returns the removed column while `DataFrame.pop` doesn't. Another difference is that `pop` can be used for both columns and rows.

Note the `inplace` argument in the `pop` method. This determines whether the DataFrame is updated in place (in this case `None` is returned and the existing DataFrame is updated) or if a DataFrame without the removed column is returned.